# HTML a href with id won't react on javascript click function

Tags: javascript, html

With tutorials I am trying to create an export option from HTML table to excel with a custom file name.

Now I got a beautiful table already in HTML.
I used many options, and I like to let this one work:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/RpKr8/
```

This is my tableToExcel.js:

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    var blob = new Blob([format(template, ctx)]);
  var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    return blobURL;

  }

})()

$("#btnExport").click(function () {
    var todaysDate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    var blobURL = tableToExcel('account_table', 'test_table');
    $(this).attr('download',todaysDate+'.xls')
    $(this).attr('href',blobURL);
});
```

This is the HTML table:

```
   <table class="table table-striped" id="account_table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            header 1
        </th>
        <th>
            header 2
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Testing Export
        </td>
        <td>
            Saved to todays date
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div>
<a class="btn btn-success" id="btnExport">Export</a>
</div>
```

My problem is that when I press the Export button, nothing happens?
I just dont get it, on every single fiddle it works.
Iam working inside an iframe, although when Iam not this happens too.

How can I fix this? Or is there another way around?

Comment: When do you call the above JavaScript? Are you sure the `a#btnExport` element exists at that time? Be sure you're running that script at the end of the `body`, or in `$(document).ready()` handler.

Comment: Do you have any errors when you run a debugger?

Comment: Also, if your table is in the `iframe` and you're trying to call Export from the outer page, I don't think you'll have access to the `table` element.

Comment: It looks like all you're doing is updating the `href` and `download` attributes of your `a` element.  This is happening during the click event and therefore will not have any visible effect on the first button click.

Comment: I edited my code. I just wrote the javascript code inside <script type="text/javascript"></script> tags. Still doesnt work. My button is inside the body and under the table

Comment: Does it need to be inside an `iframe`?  When you're not in an `iframe`, does it work?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerHTML' of null(anonymous function) @ show_gebruikers.php:27onclick @ show_gebruikers.php:116

Comment: @marc It does not work then either

Comment: I got also this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined(anonymous function) @ show_gebruikers.php:36

On this line: })()

Comment: @WillP. So is there any solution to this?

Comment: @StanvanderAvoird It's hard to say because I'm not sure why you are setting those attributes, but if you just want it to redirect to the url you could do `window.location.assign(blobURL)`

Comment: @WillP. Thank you for your effort. I just want to create an export to excel function. http://jsfiddle.net/RpKr8/ . This is the perfect example for me. But when I click the button nothing happens. I mean nothing, also when Iam adding alert('test'); to it, just to test it. It won't appear. I just dont get it.

Comment: @StanvanderAvoird interestingly, this did work for me just now in chrome, the file downloaded.  It may be different browser behavior based on the timing of the click event and the updating of the `href` attribute

Comment: @WillP. You tested it on the fiddle itself? Because It worked for me too. But once I implent it into my code, it won't work. I think its the css or something

Comment: @StanvanderAvoird I just saw your comment about the `ReferenceError` you posted.  It looks like your jquery reference isn't present in the page, and therefore the click event is not being bound

Comment: @WillP. I got it working. I really dont know what I did wrong. But I exactly copied every code from the fiddle, and slowly removed some lines. And then it suddenly worked. I had to implent the jquery-1.11.0.js and the moment.min.js else it wouldn't work.

Comment: <script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js"></script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94252/discussion-between-stan-van-der-avoird-and-will-p).

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.7.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Added these lines and it worked.

Also seperated the javscript code to:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(function(){
var tableToExcel = (function() {
  var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
    , template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>'
    , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
    , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
  return function(table, name) {
    if (!table.nodeType) table = document.getElementById(table)
    var ctx = {worksheet: name || 'Worksheet', table: table.innerHTML}
    var blob = new Blob([format(template, ctx)]);
  var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    return blobURL;
  }
})()

$("#btnExport").click(function () {
    var todaysDate = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
    var blobURL = tableToExcel('account_table', 'test_table');
    $(this).attr('download',todaysDate+'.xls')
    $(this).attr('href',blobURL);
});
});//]]> 

</script>
```